# How we fix vertical-align: middle; css property without giving height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div where i want text to verticle align without height because i have not know how much text enter by user... ##

```css
.main-body {
  display: table;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid #000;

}

.inner-body {
  display: table-cell;
}

.inner-body p {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-body">
  <div class="inner-body">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You really should edit your question so that it actually reflects the problem you are having. All the below solutions work fine with the source code in the question, so if you are having difficulties, at least show us what they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: middle;` on `.inner-body`

```css
.main-body {
  display: table;
  border:1px dotted
}

.inner-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-body">
  <div class="inner-body">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i can,t fix height please give me alternate solution without fix height?

Comment: The height was defined in your code and without height how will you recognize it's in middle? otherwise adding padding to top bottom will help.

Comment: I have updated my answer with removed height, check once.

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:middle` for `inner-body` `class`

```
.inner-body {display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;}
```

```css
.main-body {display:table; height:100px;}
.inner-body {display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;}
.inner-body p {}
```

```html
<div class="main-body">
<div class="inner-body">
<p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i can,t fix height please give me alternate solution without fix height?

Answer (score 0):

Some SO users already replied, but if you are ok with `flex` then :

```css
.inner-body { /*or .main-body*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* or flex-start for left align*/
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
HTML
<div class="main-body">
  <div class="inner-body">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

`background-color height width` are only for demonstration.

Comment: i can,t fix height please give me alternate solution without fix height?

Comment: _`background-color height width` are only for demonstration_  just use `height:auto;` also since this is a text please add: `text-align: ______ ;` where ____ is `center` or `left` or `right`